# Responsive Design-making

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

i am making the design for desktop as well as mobile version but i am stuck with the position of buttons here  i write the positioning css for button id "three,four,five,six,seven,eight" for desktop version and write the another positioning css for all for mobile version in "@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){}" but the problem is when i switch on the desktop version it takes the positioning css for mobile version. what should i do to solve this.

```
i have tried the important keyword but it shows the same behavior. 

#three,#four{
 background-color:blue;
 position: relative ;
 left: 380px ;
 top:0px ss;
 }
 #five,#six{
    background-color: #FFA500;
    position: relative;
     left: 0px; 
     top: 0px; 
 }
 #seven,#eight{
    background-color:  #4c4c4c;
    position: relative;
    left: 380px;
    top: 0
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
#three{
    position: relative;
    left: 291px;
    top: 137px;
 }
 #five{
    position: relative;
    left: 291px;
    top: 141px;
}
 #seven{
    position: relative;
    left: 289px;
    top: 136px;
 }
 #two{
    position: relative;
    left: 291px;
    top: 94px;
 }
 #four{
    position: relative;
    left: 293px;
    top: 94px;
 }
 #six{
    position: relative;
    left: 296px;
    top: 94px;
 }
 #eight{
    position: relative;
    left: 295px;
    top: 94px;
}
}
this is the code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I go about designing for the web responsively is to use a mobile first workflow. This means your default styles without media queries are for mobile.

Then using:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Only applies to bigger than 768px */
}
```

This approach means using !important isn't necessary if your CSS file is ordered correctly, with mobile at the top and moving upwards.

Comment: but my default style without media query is for desktop  and when i am going to see the mobile view it work correctly but desktop version is not taking the position that i given without  media query or default css.

Comment: actully the css that i give in media query section is override the default desktop view section.and this    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Only applies to bigger than 768px */
}   didn't  work.

Comment: @RAHULKHOWAL could you upload your code to codepen or something so I can debug it properly